# Подсчет количества записей в окне с рамкой по времени

Tags: sql, postgresql

Коллеги, не могу решить задачу.

Нужно посчитать среднее количество записей по content_id с первой записи в течение 36 часов. Пока пытаюсь вообще посчитать количество записей по пользователям, но не могу наладить код:

```
    select 
        content_id,
        count(user_id) over (partition by content_id 
                                    order by show_date ASC
                                    RANGE BETWEEN first_value(show_date)
                                    AND first_value(show_date) + INTERVAL '36 hours')
    from test_watch
```

Comment: COUNT() считает количество, соответственно сортировка явно лишняя - вот какая разница, считать с конца, с начала или как попало, а? RANGE задаётся не абсолютным значением, а смещением от текущей записи - т.е. либо это CURRENT ROW, либо сколько-то PRECEDING/FOLLOWING. К тому же оконная функция в определении окна использоваться не может в принципе. Изучите внимательнее определение окна и вообще его смысл.

Comment: Сортировку делаю для того, чтобы найти время первой записи. И как отталкиваться от строк, если у меня окно определяется рамкой времени а не количеством строк? В требуемый период может входить 1 строка, а может 100.